# Problems with including fontawesome in a moderncv template

Tags: moderncv, fontawesome

I have a problem with including the fontawesome in my moderncv template. It doesn't show any problem after compiling but it doesn't use the new iconset for mobile, phone, fax etc.

I used the following code:

```
    \documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv} 

    \moderncvstyle{casual} 
    \moderncvcolor{blue} 
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry} % Reduce document margins

    \usepackage{fontawesome}
    \usepackage{fontenc}
    \moderncvicons{awesome}
```

Miktec shows the problem:

lualatex> ! Undefined control sequence.

lualatex>  \moderncvicons

lualatex>

lualatex> l.38 \moderncvicons

lualatex>                  {awesome}

Can anybody help with that?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP used an outdated version of moderncv.

Answer (score 0):

I accidentally used an old version of moderncv (1.4.0). I have it now updated and it works properly. Thanks anyway!